# Can the SMS forwarding number be removed from the reply using Twilio's to forward SMS messages to another phone number?

Tags: sms, message

I want to use Twilio to create an SMS relaying service where the Twilio number is the only number that is exposed, much like web proxy servers that allow you to access the Internet anonymously.  I've used  the example php code that twilio provides, saved it to a php file and hosted it on a public web server, then updated the messages URL on the Twilio site accordingly. Any message sent to the Twilio number the is forwarded to my mobile. Everything works fine, except for the fact that when I reply to the forwarded message from my phone, the reply includes a header that says "Sent from your Twilio trial account - + mymobilenumber" I understand that the header is inserted because I have a trial account, however I don't want the mymobilenumber field to be exposed.  Is it possible to hide this?
I should mention I'm not really a programmer but I'm learning with Twilio.
I followed the example given here:
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-forward-my-sms-messages-to-another-phone-number

Thx
Antonio

Answer (score -1):

A short code is a 5 or 6-digit number that can send and receive messages with mobile phones. These high-throughput numbers are perfect for apps that need to send messages to lots of users or need to send time sensitive messages. You can buy shortcodes from Twilio or port existing short codes to our platform.